# How to retrieve the markers for py.test in conftest.py?

Tags: python, pytest

I am running tests with `py.test` and want to access the markers I have set on the command line. I have tried the following code inside `conftest.py` (based on the documentation I found [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.7.3/plugins.html)) in a fixture that is used by every running test (i.e. a fixture that setup the test):

```
@pytest.fixture
def basedriver(request):
    ...
    node = request.node
    print("Marker: %s" % str(node.get_marker('set1')))
    ...
```

but when I invoke the test like follows:

```
py.test -s -m "set1 or ready"
```

I get the following output

```
Marker: None
```

I seem to do it wrong. How to do it right?

Ideally, I can retrieve the *whole* string, i.e. "set1 or ready"...

Comment: try `str(node.get_marker('set1'))`

Comment: If is would have worked it would not be 'None'. I will update the question...

Comment: [They updated it which fixes this issue with a new function.](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/mark.html) @Alex

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`request.node` is the test function object, so `request.node.get_closest_marker('set1')` returns the marker attached to the test currently being executed, or `None` if a marker with the name cannot be found. For example, running a test

```
@pytest.fixture
def basedriver(request):
    node = request.node
    print('Marker:', node.get_closest_marker('set1'))

@pytest.mark.set1
def test_spam(basedriver):
    assert True

def test_eggs(basedriver):
    assert True
```

will print

```
test_spam.py::test_spam Marker: MarkInfo(_marks=[Mark(name='set1', args=(), kwargs={})])
PASSED
test_spam.py::test_eggs Marker: None
PASSED
```

What you want is the passed value of the command line argument `-m`. Access it via config fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture
def basedriver(pytestconfig):
    markers_arg = pytestconfig.getoption('-m')
    print('markers passed from command line:', markers_arg)
    ...
```

Comment: Oh cool, its more simple than I thought. And kind of trivial simple ;-)... Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help! You may also find this recipe for modifying test run logic depending on cli args helpful: [Pass different values to a test function, depending on command line options](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#pass-different-values-to-a-test-function-depending-on-command-line-options).

Comment: the `get_marker` function no longer exists in pytest 4, use `get_closest_marker` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the

```
`request.node.get_marker('set1') `
```

is not working anymore.
But you can change it to:

```
request.node.get_closest_marker('set1')
```

see:

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/historical-notes.html#update-marker-code

Answer (score 1):

Came across this while looking for a way to find markers that a test has been marked with and the previous answers weren't working for me since `get_closest_marker('set1')` requires "hard-coding" a value and what I wanted was to be able to grab and log the current marker **without knowing what it "should" be**.

Below example helped me with my use case.

```
    import pytest
    from loguru import logger


    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def get_marker(request):
        markers = request.node.own_markers
        for marker in markers:
            logger.info(f'Marker: {marker.name}')
    
    
    @pytest.mark.tagged
    @pytest.mark.tagged_again
    def test_tag_test():
        logger.info('This is a tagged test')
    
    
    def test_non_tag_test():
        logger.info('This is NOT a tagged test')
```

Output:

> 23/Aug/2022 10:8:9 - INFO: Marker: tagged_again
> 23/Aug/2022 10:8:9   - INFO: Marker: tagged
> 23/Aug/2022 10:8:9   - INFO: This is a tagged test